# Exchange 2007 Resource Calendars Automatically Booking

Tags: exchange-2007, calendar

I have a resource mailbox that I would like all meeting requests to be approved by resource delegates. Below is a dump of the calendar properties for the resource mailbox. Currently any user part of `Booking Group` will have their requests automatically approved even though `AllBookInPolicy` is false and `BookInPolicy` is null. Any ideas as to what I'm missing to get this to work? Below is a dump of the resource calendar's properties.

```
AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept
AllowConflicts                      : True
BookingWindowInDays                 : 180
MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False
ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
MaximumConflictInstances            : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
DeleteAttachments                   : True
DeleteComments                      : True
RemovePrivateProperty               : True
DeleteSubject                       : True
DisableReminders                    : True
AddOrganizerToSubject               : True
DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
TentativePendingApproval            : True
EnableResponseDetails               : True
OrganizerInfo                       : True
ResourceDelegates                   : {User 1, User 2, User 3}
RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {Booking Group}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
BookInPolicy                        :
AllBookInPolicy                     : False
RequestInPolicy                     : {Booking Group}
AllRequestInPolicy                  : False
AddAdditionalResponse               : False
AdditionalResponse                  :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True
AddNewRequestsTentatively           : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
DefaultReminderTime                 : 15
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
```

Comment: Logged into OWA, opened the resource calendar's mailbox, clicked "Options" then "Resource Settings".
Under the radio button for "Resource Scheduling Permissions" the menu item "**These users can schedule automatically if the resource is available and can submit a request for manual approval if the resource is unavailable:**" was set to "Select Users and Groups:" and the field was auto-populated with `Booking Group`. Removing `Booking Group` and saving the settings fixed the issue and requests are now properly being forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

AutomateProcessing - If this parameter is set to AutoAccept, both the Calendar Attendant and resource booking attendant are enabled on the mailbox. This means that the Calendar Attendant updates the calendar, and then the resource booking assistant accepts the meeting based upon the policies

You need to set this to **AutoUpdate**, that way only the Calendar Attendant processes meeting requests and responses.